# Fast algorithm for establishing mutual independence

Tags: independence, algorithms

According to the definition, a set $S$ of random variables is mutually independent iff every event is independent of any intersection of the other events.  Thus, checking a set of random variables for mutual independence by this definition requires checking *almost* every subset of $S$, which is on the order of $2^{|S|}$ checks (not even counting the time to check if a set is $k$-wise independent).  Do you know of any theorems of the sort "if [some criterion $X$] then the elements of $S$ are mutually independent" where checking criterion $X$ is sub-exponential, or of any results proving that this problem is NP?

**BONUS:** any comments with references to any *open* works that contain boatloads of theorems about mutual independence will get upvotes.

Comment: Your "definition" is redundant: "$k$-wise independent" when $k=|S|$ *means* mutually independent.  Subsets need not be checked.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_events.  In light of this, there is no question to be answered here.

Comment: I misunderstood the definition of k-wise independence.  Updated the definition.  The question still makes sense, I think.  The subsets DO need to be checked:  The definition on wikipedia you cited specifically uses the language "for any finite subset".

Comment: e.g. assuming I can check pairwise independence efficiently by having easily-integrable characteristic equations on hand, I STILL have to check independence between every element of $S$ and every subset of $S$.  OTOH, checking pairwise independence would be an $O(|S|^2)$ operation.

Comment: Is your question truly "fully general" or do you have a set $S$ in mind?

Comment: I do not have a set $S$ in mind, but I would be interested in specific examples of where this would be easy to do.  E.g. It is trivial to prove that random variables over different components from a product distribution are mutually independent.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to be able to check this efficiently, approximately, for sample distributions.

Comment: I think you might still misunderstand the Wikipedia article. It has in mind stochastic processes, for which $|S|$ is *infinite*.  The content of its statement (which is a consequence of a stronger theorem of Kolmogorov) is that you *only* have to check independence of all finite subsets.  This obviously is a theoretical, not a practical, matter.

Comment: @whuber, and yet, would you would agree that checking each random variable $X$ in $S$ against all subsets of $S$ would establish mutual independence?  You seem to be suggesting that there is a more practical solution to the problem than that, but are reluctant to state it.  If you have such knowledge, feel free to post that solution as an answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what the problem is, Scott: you haven't described any data, so maybe you have a particular theoretical situation in mind, but you haven't described that, either.

Comment: I don't have a particular theoretical solution in mind, hence the question.  If you want a specific case, I can pick one arbitrarily.  Suppose $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are discrete random variables over $\{0,1\}$.  The naive way to check for mutual independence is to check that the events $X_1=0$ and $X_2=0$ are independent, that $X_2=0$, $X_3=0$ are independent, that $X_1=0$, $X_3=0$ are independent (now we're up to $O(n^2)$), mutual independence is still not established, we need to check that $P(X_1=0,X_2=0,X_3=0) = P(X_1=0)P(X_2=0)P(X_3=0)$.  This is an $O(2^n)$ sequence of computations.